# Delays in confirmation

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I have a bitcoin transaction which still hasn't confirmed in the last 3 hours. Any luck on how to make it fast?

I added the nominal 0.0001 fee that is common for all transactions.

Answer (score 2):

Some times the network takes a bit longer to find a block but that does not seem to be the case right now, since there are plenty of blocks found in the last couple of hours?

Is your transaction already included in a block? If not it should be the fee that is on the lowish side.

It really depends on the size (in bytes) of your transaction.
You could check [statoshi](http://statoshi.info/dashboard/db/fee-estimates) to estimate the fee for your transactions, depending on the amount of time you are willing to wait.

Comment: You can also try to look your transaction on blockonomics.co to get an estimate of confirmation time